# Why cant I use min function in my xslt on a number

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am trying to use the min function on numbers. In the documentation I have seen its possible to use integers as input. I Have also tried number($test2) without result.

```
<xsl:variable name="test2" select="string-length(substring-before($resourcepath, 'se'))" />
<xsl:variable name="test3" select="min($test2 , $test2 )" />
```

> Required item type of second argument of min() is xs:string; supplied
>   value has item type xs:integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to use the min function on numbers.

The min() function works on **sequences**, not on numbers directly. Instead of:

```
min($a, $b)
```

try:

```
min(($a, $b))
```

Otherwise the function expects $b to be the optional *collation* argument (which needs to be a string).